# Using pointers to copy an array

Tags: c++, pointers, function-call, function-declaration, stdarray

I'm trying to copy the contents of `array1` to `array2` using a self-written function called `ArrayCopy()`. The arrays are both the same size. I have to use pointers to do it.

I know that the integers in `array1` are copying over to `array2`, but when I print `array2` outside of the `ArrayCopy()` function, it still prints with all 0s. I know `array1` is successfully getting values from `cin`.

I cannot change the block of code at the end of `main()`, otherwise I will lose points on the assignment.

Part of `ArrayCopy()` is commented out, but it's just something I tried that didn't work.

For testing, the values I've entered for `array1` are `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>

const int ARRAYSIZE = 5;

void ArrayCopy(std::array<int, ARRAYSIZE>, std::array<int, ARRAYSIZE>);

int main() {

    std::array<int, ARRAYSIZE> array1;
    std::array<int, ARRAYSIZE> array2 = {};
    
    std::cout << "Please input " << ARRAYSIZE << " integers: ";

    // Get user input into array1

    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++) {

        std::cin >> array1[i];

        }

  // DO NOT CHANGE THIS CODE
    std::cout << "\n\nBefore copy, array 1 is: \n";
    PrintArray(array1);
    std::cout << "\nAnd array 2 is: \n";
    PrintArray(array2, ARRAYSIZE);

    ArrayCopy(array1, array2);

    std::cout << "\n\nAfter copy, array 1 is: \n";
    PrintArray(array1);
    std::cout << "\nAnd array 2 is: \n";
    PrintArray(array2, ARRAYSIZE);

   // END CODE THAT YOU SHOULD NOT CHANGE

}

void ArrayCopy(std::array<int, ARRAYSIZE> array1, std::array<int, ARRAYSIZE> array2) {

    for (size_t i = 0; i < array1.size(); i++) {

        int *holder1 = &array1[i];
        int *holder2 = &array2[i];

        array2[i] = *holder1;

        /*
        int* temp = holder2;

        holder2 = holder1;
        holder1 = temp;

        int holderInteger = *holder2;

        std::cout << holderInteger;

        array2[i] = holderInteger;
        */

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to pass arrays by reference.

Comment: What's wrong with `std::copy()` to use in that case??

Comment: *I'm trying to copy the contents of array1 to array2 using a self-written function* -- Your function has bugs and is slower than what the standard library provides.   What's your reason for writing your own function?  `std::copy(array1.begin(), array1.end(), array2.begin());`  or just `array2 = array1;`

Comment: Related: [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/) and [How to pass objects to functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass arrays by reference as for example

```
void ArrayCopy( const std::array<int, ARRAYSIZE> &array1, std::array<int, ARRAYSIZE> &array2) {

    for (size_t i = 0; i < array1.size(); i++) {

        const int *holder1 = &array1[i];
        int *holder2 = &array2[i];

        *holder2 = *holder1;
    }
}
```

Otherwise the function deals with copies of the original arrays.

Pay attention to that you could just assign one array to another like

```
array2 = array1;
```

For example

```
void ArrayCopy( const std::array<int, ARRAYSIZE> &array1, std::array<int, ARRAYSIZE> &array2) {
    array2 = array1;
}
```

Comment: I can't do that without changing the function call in main. The function call is in the code block that I can't change.

I would try to create pointers for the arrays before that, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: @Faraday12 The function call will be the same without any changes ArrayCopy(array1, array2);

Comment: @Faraday12 -- I know it's hard to believe, but simply doing `array2 = array1;` in `ArrayCopy` does everything you were trying to do with all of that code with pointers.  You were trying to open the door by pushing on the door, throwing your weight on the door, using sledgehammers, etc. instead of just pulling on the door to open it.

Comment: @Vlad Thank you so much. I thought by changing the function parameters passed in at the definition would require changing the function call as well, but I guess not. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the array by value. That means when you call `ArrayCopy(array1, array2);`, a copy of array1 and array2 is passed to the function. Your copying inside the function only copies into the copy of array2.

A solution is to change the type of the parameter the function receives to `std::array<int, ARRAYSIZE>&`. The & after a typename means it is a reference, so when you call the function a *reference* to your array is passed to the function and your function modifies the original array.